# How to call this.getView() in a callback

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I want to change the compact density with a button.

```js
onInit: function () {
  this.getView().addStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact");
},
```

works well. If I will change it in a button, it does not work.

```js
onOpenDialog: function (oEvent) {
  var oDialog1 = new Dialog();
  // ...
  oDialog1.addButton(new Button({
    text: "OK",
    press: function () {
      // How can I point to the view from inside this function?
    }
  }));
  oDialog1.open();
},
```

**How can I point to the view from inside the function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you had to ask, since it's basic Javascript, really...

Since `press` is invoked from `oToggleButton`, the `this` keyword now holds a reference to `oToggleButton`, and **not** the controller (hence why the `getView()` method fails). Search for 'this keyword in inner function' for more info.

To solve this, simply add a reference to this outside the inner function:

`var that = this;`

and in your inner function, use the reference instead:

`that.getView().addStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact");`